# Asserting Number of executed unit-tests

Tags: jenkins, django-jenkins

I am using Jenkins to run unit-tests on a Django project via django-jenkins.

Recently, I found that some of the unit-tests wasn't being executed (someone had mistakenly changed an `import`, causing Jenkins to miss some of the unit-test files).

Is there a way to `assert` on the number of tests that Jenkins executes?, or the number of test-packages?

Answer (score 0):

It could be tricky in python.

But you could add additional shell command that just looks into junit report.

```
cat reports/junit.xml | grep 'classname="your.missing.test.name"'
```

command would fail if `grep` doesn't found test record.

Or do the `sudo apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl` and assert on `tests` attibute value

```
[ $(xpath  -q -e '//@tests' reports/junit.xml) == 'tests="1"' ]
```